# I cannot connect Laravel project with VueJS project on localhost

Tags: laravel, vue.js, localhost, port, hosts

I clone my company Laravel project to my computer and run on localhost (set as name ecomlocal.com), port 80
Then, I continue clone Vue JS project, and run on localhost 8080 (ecomlocal.com:8080)

The problem is, VueJs Project calls to API storing at Laravel Project, (An API example: http://ecomlocal.com:8080/api/...) so the error "404 not found API" occur because exactly API is http://ecomlocal.com/api/...

[The error show when calling API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoIZI.png)

I have tried to set up my localhost to rename port 8080 as ecomlocal.com (that has the same port with Laravel Project) but it doesn't work.

```
// my hosts file
127.0.0.1 ecomlocal.com  -> it works

127.0.0.1:8080 ecomlocal.com -> it doesn't
0.0.0.0:8080 ecomlocal.com -> nether does it
```

[Host file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUJWs.png)

Because They're company projects, I can not change/modify directly on Project./
I think it'd better to use them on same port but i have no idea to do it.

Can you help me ? Thanks you guys alot

Comment: Why don't you just call http://ecomlocal.com/api/ in your Vue js?

Comment: My vueJs API has been set as "/api/..." for thousands files, and I can't modify it :((
and other employees in my company have no problem with this.

Comment: why don't you simply set baseURL in ```.env``` and access api by using that URL, you can simply ```php artisan serve``` and then change baseURL on production server.

Comment: I think this is a bad practice to call a hard-coded API from different files. A better way is suggested by Salman Malik.